# Displaying 20 words from the beginning of the chain in Python

Tags: python, django, html

```
<tbody>
    {%for wpis in wpisy%}
    <tr> 
        <td ><a href="/{{wpis.nick}}">{{wpis.nick}}</a></td>
        <td>{{wpis.tresc}}</td>
    </tr>
    {%endfor%}
</tbody>
```

I would like to display only 20 words from the beginning of the string, but I have no idea how to do it.

I tried to do it like this:

```
<td>{{wpis.tresc.split(" ")[:20]}}</td>
```

Comment: Are you using **templates** such like Jinja2? Are you using Flask or django?

Comment: I'm using django.The idea is that the user enters in the form some text, and I want to write only the first 20 words of this text in the table.The whole text appears on the other webside, but I have done it already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at the `truncatewords` template tag.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords

You would do something similar to this: `{{ wpis.nick|truncatewords:20 }}`